# how to handle NULL values in DATE type column on where statement

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine, flask, google-bigquery

I run the SQL below in Python to Google BigQuery but I got error `BadRequest: 400 Could not cast literal "" to type DATE` 
I want to check the data in cv_date column that is same row of luid exists or not and if it exists , it return True. cv_date column is DATE type. I tried use `cv_date IS NOT NULL` but it didn't work . anyone has idea ?? or I need to change the logic of this SQL ??

```
from flask import Flask, request
from google.cloud import bigquery


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def get_request():
    request_luid = request.args.get('luid') or ''
    client = bigquery.Client()
    query = """SELECT EXISTS(
                    SELECT 1
                    FROM `test-266778.conversion_log.conversion_log_2020*` as p
                    WHERE p.luid = '{}' 
                    AND p.cv_date != '' limit 1000)""".format(request_luid)

    
    job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig(
        query_parameters=[
            bigquery.ScalarQueryParameter("request_luid", "STRING", request_luid)
        ]
    )
    
    query_job = client.query(query)
    query_res = query_job.result()
     
     for row in query_res:
        return str(row[0])
       
        


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Comment: Indeed the error will be solved by changing `!= ""` to `IS NOT NULL`. As an example consider the query:   `SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1  FROM bigquery-public-data.austin_waste.waste_and_diversion  as p   WHERE p.load_id = 336590  AND p.report_date IS NOT NULL  limit 1000 )` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am not mistaken, you want to check if the Date column exists or not for every row with a certain luid.

Continuing with my public bigquery data example I believe you want something similar to:

```
SELECT load_id,report_date IS NOT NULL as date
FROM `bigquery-public-data.austin_waste.waste_and_diversion` as p
limit 1000
```

for a specific luid, which in your case would be something like

```
"""SELECT luid,cv_date IS NOT NULL as date
FROM `<project-id>.conversion_log.conversion_log_2020*` as p
where p.luid = '{}' 
limit 1000""".format(request_luid)
```

Comment: Than you for your advice . As you advice , I tried using IS NOT NULL again and that works . Actually , I'm not sure why it didn't work before with same code I'm using now.